# msDropDown Delete all options

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, msdropdown

Please let me know how can I remove/clear all options from msDropDown. I have tried the below code and its not working fine.

```
    oHandler2 = $("#main").msDropDown().data("dd"); 
    oHandler2.remove();
```

Thanks in Advance.
Lampy

Comment: it looks like remove takes a parameter - the index of the item to remove.

Comment: Is there any functions available to clear all options? OR Can i get the count of items in the dropdown?

Comment: Not sure, you could try the .destroy() method.

Comment: `.destroy()` turns it into a regular select input. You could then check remove the options using `$('#main options').remove()`, but then he would have to convert back to msDropDown afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify an index when calling the `.remove()` method and you can get the count of all options by accessing the `childElementCount` property. Then you just need to remove all the options. Example below:

```
var oHandler2 = $("#main").msDropDown().data("dd");

for(var i = 0; i < oHandler2.childElementCount; i++){
    oHandler2.remove(0); //remove the current first option
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to delete all item is

```
var oHandler = $("#main").msDropDown().data("dd");
oHandler.set("length", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to remove specify item, you can delete your element. And then create new one.

HTML

```
<div class="mainSection">
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
   $("#main").remove();
   $(".mainSection").append("<div id='main'></div>");
   $("#main").msDropDown().data("dd"); 
</script>
```